# Expiring all caches on a controller

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a resourceful controller with a custom action. The action is pretty heavy, so I'm working on caching it:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :walk_to_mordor

  # GET /my/:id/walk_to_mordor/:direction
  def walk_to_mordor
    # srz bzns
  end
end
```

It works very nice, caching is done and the page is now fast. However, I want to allow the user to "bust" the cache by clicking on a link on the page. At first I tried:

```
def bust_cache
  expire_action :action => :walk_to_mordor
end
```

Rails complained that no route matches my action. Might be because of the parameter. Hmm, let's give it to him:

```
def bust_cache
  MyEntities.all.each do |e|
    expire_action walk_to_mordor_path(e, ??)
  end
end
```

Problem, I can't possibly identify all choices of `:direction`.

Is there a way to clear all action caches that match a certain regular expression, or all action caches from a specific controller?

Comment: One does not simply walk into mordor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret is called `expire_fragment`:

> **expire_fragment(key, options = nil)**
>
> Removes fragments from the cache.
>
> key can take one of three forms:
>
> - String - This would normally take the form of a path, like "pages/45/notes".
> - Hash - Treated as an implicit call to `url_for`, like `{:controller => "pages", :action => "notes", :id => 45}`
> - Regexp - Will remove any fragment that matches, so `%r{pages/d*/notes}` might remove all notes. Make sure you don’t use anchors in the regex (`^` or `$`) because the actual filename matched looks like `./cache/filename/path.cache`. Note: Regexp expiration is only supported on caches that can iterate over all keys (unlike memcached).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment

Sadly, it won't work with memcached (if I ever decide to use it). Gotta be a lot more clever to avoid cache in that circunstance. Maybe adding a `serial` parameter to the request, and increment it when the user presses the 'bust cache' button...